# Django save variable from views to models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need help with one thing in my django project.

I have class games in my views.py which is connected to the path in URLs. The game's class can now take the game_id, player_id, and score values and then use a variable to output them on the result.html page, which works.

Instead of listing these values on the page, I need to store these values in a SQL database in Django in a pre-created location using models.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user_rec = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    game1_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    game2_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    game3_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s's Subscription Info" % self.user_rec


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from authentication.models import Profile
from rocnikovka import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode,urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_str
from . tokens import generate_token




def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # username = request.POST.get("username") 
        username = request.POST["username"]
        fname = request.POST["fname"]
        lname = request.POST["lname"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        pass1 = request.POST["pass1"]
        pass2 = request.POST["pass2"]

        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            messages.error(request, "Username already exist! Please try some other username.")
            return redirect("home")

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, "Email Address already registered! ")
            return redirect("home")

        if len(username)>20:
            messages.error(request, "Username must be under 20 characters.")
            return redirect('home')

        if pass1 != pass2:
             messages.error(request, "Passwords did not match")
             return redirect('home') 

        if not username.isalnum():
            messages.error(request, "Username must be Alpha-numeric!")
            return redirect("home")

        myuser =  User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.is_active = False
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request,"Your account has been succesfully created. We have sent you a confirmation email, please confirm your email in order to activate your account. ")

        # Welcome Email

        subject = "Welcome to our games sites"
        message="Hello " + myuser.first_name + "!! \n" + "Welcome to our games sites!! \n Thank you for visiting our website \n we have also sent you a confirmation email, please confirm your email address in order to activate your account, \n\n Thanking you, \n Jiří Bezděkovský"
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list = [myuser.email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email,to_list,fail_silently=True )

        # Email Address confirmation Email
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        email_subject ="Confirm your email in games sites"
        message2 = render_to_string('email_confirmation.html',{
            
            'name': myuser.first_name,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(myuser.pk)),
            'token': generate_token.make_token(myuser)
        })
        email = EmailMessage(
        email_subject,
        message2,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [myuser.email],
        )
        email.fail_silently = True
        email.send()
        
        return redirect("signin")

    return render(request, "authentication/signup.html")

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid=force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        myuser=User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        myuser=None

    if myuser is not None and generate_token.check_token(myuser, token):
        myuser.is_active = True
        myuser.save()
        login(request, myuser)
        messages.success(request, "Your Account has been activated!!")
        return redirect("signin") 
    else: 
        return render(request, "activation_failed.html")

def signin(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        pass1 =  request.POST["pass1"]

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=pass1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            fname = user.first_name     
            return render(request, "home.html", {"fname": fname})
        else: 
            messages.error(request, "Bad Credentials!")
            return redirect("home")

    return render(request, "authentication/signin.html")

def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "Logged Out Successfully!")
    return redirect("home")
    # return render(request, "authentication/signout.html")

def unity(request):
    return render(request, template_name='index.html')

def update_profile(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.profile.bio = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...'
    user.save()



def games(request, game_id, player_id, score):


    
    return render(request, 'result.html',{'game_id' : game_id, 'player_id' : player_id, "score" : score}   )
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from authentication import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"),
    path("home",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"),
    path("one",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="one.html"), name="one"),
    path("two",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="two.html"), name="two"),
    path("three",TemplateView.as_view(template_name="three.html"), name="three"),
     path("signin", views.signin, name="signin"), 
     path("signup", views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('index', include("authentication.urls")), 
    path('lumberjack/', views.unity, name='unity'),
    path('products/<int:game_id>/<int:player_id>/<int:score>',views.games, name="games"),
]
```

I've really tried a lot of variations and I still can't figure out how to do it.
Could someone please help me create this?

Comment: the simplest way could be create a model like `UserGameScore` with 2 fields `ForeignKey` to `User` (as before) and `Game` and a simple field for score. YOu also need to create a simple `Game` model. Then, inside your `games` view create an object based on url values, i.e.  `UserGameScore.objects.create()`. Try to validate the data before creating an object.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need to clarify a few things. What should I add to the Game model and if I need my Profile model or not after these changes?

Comment: You're welcome. (_if I need my Profile model or not after these changes_) It all depends on how you design your database. I don't know why you put `game1|2|3_score` inside `Profile`, but you can move them to `Game` model. In my opinion, `Game` and `Profile` models should have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I need game1/2/3_score, because I have three games and I must connect score to right game, where should I put them? I want the database to have a user who has basic data to authenticate and then to be able to save scores for three different games, using views which is what we are doing now.  And also can you paste the line with UserGameScore.objects.create(), I have something, but also get errors.